# wordpress ajax post to database

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress code snippet plugin to write my javascript codes.
as I'm pretty new to wordpress coding, I tried doing an AJAX post that saves some data to the database like the title of the current post being viewed.
I followed the solution in this post: [How to store form data using wordpress ajax in db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721149/how-to-store-form-data-using-wordpress-ajax-in-db)

here's my javascript code written in the Code Snippet Plugin

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { 

    global $post;


    
?>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
$("#myButton").click(function(){            
    
    var pname = "<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>";
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        
    data: { 
        'action' : 'myFunction',
        'pname': pname
       
    },
    success: function(data){
        if (data.res == true){
            alert(data.message);    // success message
        }else{
            alert(data.message);    // fail
        }
    }
}); //end ajax post

    }); //end click function

}); //end jqjuery document ready function
    


</script>
```

now here's what I put in my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunction', 'myFunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myFunction', 'myFunction' );
function myFunction(){
global $wpdb;

$pname = $_POST["pname"];
$browsing_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

$tableName = 'myTable';
$insert_row = $wpdb->insert( 
                $tableName, 
                array( 
                    'browsing_date' => $browsing_date,
                    'page_name' => $pname
                  
                )
            );
// if row inserted in table
if($insert_row){
    echo json_encode(array('res'=>true, 'message'=>__('New row has been inserted.')));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('res'=>false, 'message'=>__('Something went wrong. Please try again later.')));
}
wp_die();
}
```

now when I click myButton, and look at the console of my browser, it says that there was a POST event but there was no inserted data in myTable and the

```
> success: function(data){
        if (data.res == true){
            alert(data.message);    // success message
        }else{
            alert(data.message);    // fail
        }
```

is not being called. your wisdom would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try var_dump($insert_row) ?

Comment: hi, Fixed it just used value for $tablename as $wpdb->prefix . 'myTable';

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by using $wpdb->prefix . 'myTable'; as the value of $tablename